# Bound on the cardinality of the union of a chain

Tags: set-theory

I was trying to go through the proof that submodules of free modules over a principal ideal domain are free and I ran into a set theoretic cardinality problem that I can't find answered anywhere:  Suppose I have an index set $I$, and two chains {$U_{i}$}$_{i\in I}$ and {$V_{i}$}$_{i\in I}$ such that for each $i$, $\mid U_{i}\mid\leq\mid V_{i}\mid$.  Is it necessarily true that $\mid\bigcup _{i\in I} U_{i}\mid\leq\mid\bigcup _{i\in I} V_{i}\mid$?  I can see that this is not true if one doesn't assume the collections are directed families.  I've tried well-ordering $I$ and trying to make an injection using transfinite induction by constructing the collection {$C_{i}$}$_{i\in I}$, where $C_{i}=U_{i}\setminus\bigcup _{j<i}U_{j}$ but it's getting me nowhere.  I feel like this should be obvious.

Comment: For a counterexample take $\omega_1$ as index set, $U_i = i$, and $V_i = \omega$ for all $i$.

Comment: I think it's true if you assume that $(I,\lt)$ is totally ordered; $|U_i|\le|V_i|$ for each $i$; $U_i\subseteq U_j$ whenever $i\lt j$; and $V_i\subsetneqq V_j$ whenever $i\lt j$. Would that be good enough?

Comment: Proof of @bof's claim: Let $V = \bigcup_i V_i$. Clearly $|I \times V| \geq |\bigcup_i U_i|$. The additional assumption implies $|V| \geq |I|$, so $|I \times V| = \max(|I|, |V|) = |V|$ (for infinite sets that is; the finite case is easy).

Comment: @VilleSalo $|V|\ge|I|$ does not necessarily follow, e.g. if $I=\mathbb R$ and $V_i=\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\lt i\}$, but we can replace $I$ with a cofinal well-ordered subset $J$ and then everything is fine, $|V|\ge|J|$ etc.

Comment: Good point. Easy to trip up on these things (if you are not a set theorist).